# Laravel 5 session expire after refresh

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I use laravel Auth. I am login into my website all works great. When I try refresh or go to other page(still use Auth middleware) my session is expired and i must login again. I check it on ftp, using other browsers. I try change variables in config/session.php. I have no idea how to fix it.

This is my session.php file

```
    <?php

return [
    'driver' => 'file',
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => true,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path().'/framework/sessions',
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,

];
```

Comment: did you have `session_start();` code on top of your each page?

Comment: no, few weeks ago when i try to learn laravel all works without this line, i will check it.

Comment: Please check the link:- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-creates-a-new-session-after-each-request

Comment: Hello check that session storage folder has  permission for write

Comment: it doesn't work, i try in new laravel instalation but still expire

Comment: So, i found why it doesn't work. Don't use this line.
<li><a href="{{ Auth::logout() }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>